# Unpacking bitfields with c++ produces wrong result

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I am trying to unpack mp3 frames using bitfields.

The header of mp3 frames starts with the syncword 0xFFF followed by 20 bits of header data. The structure of the header is represented as follows:

```
struct Mp3FrameRaw {
  unsigned short fff:12; // Should always be 0xFFF = 4095
  unsigned short mpeg_standard : 1;
  unsigned short layer : 2;
  unsigned short error_protection : 1;
  unsigned short bitrate : 4;
  unsigned short frequency : 2;
  unsigned short pad_bit : 1;
  unsigned short  : 1;
  unsigned short mode :2;
  unsigned short mode_extension :2;
  unsigned short copyrighted : 1;
  unsigned short original: 1;
  unsigned short emphasis: 2;
};
```

In total the header is 32 bit long.

My program first finds the syncword:

```
size_t find_sync_word(std::vector<unsigned char> & input) {
  bool previous_was_ff = false;

  for (size_t offset = 0; offset < input.size(); ++offset) {
    if (previous_was_ff && (input[offset] & 0xF0 == 0xF0))
      return offset - 1;
    previous_was_ff = 0xFF == input[offset];
  }
  return -1;
}
```

And then tries to unpack the first header:

```
int parse(std::vector<unsigned char> & input) {
  size_t offset = find_sync_word(input);
  if (offset < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Not a valid Mp3 file" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  Mp3FrameRaw *frame_ptr = reinterpret_cast<Mp3FrameRaw * >(input.data() + offset);
  std::cout << frame_ptr->fff << " (Should always be 4095)" << std::endl;
  std::cout << frame_ptr->layer << " (Should be 1 )" << std::endl;
  std::cout << frame_ptr->bitrate << " (Should be 1-14)" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The `main.cpp` reads:

```
 int main() {
  std::ifstream mp3_file("/path/to/file.mp3", std::ios::binary);
  std::vector<unsigned char> file_contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(mp3_file)),
                                           std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

  return parse(file_contents);
 }
```

The result reads:

```
3071 (Should always be 4095)
3 (Should be 1 )
0 (Should be 1 - 14)
```

Contrary, if I unpack the fields manually bit by bit, everything works as expected. e.g

```
{
    size_t offset;
    Mp3FrameRaw frame;        
    ...

    frame.fff = input[offset++];
    frame.fff = (frame.fff << 4) | (input[offset] >> 4);

    frame.mpeg_standard = (input[offset] >> 3) & 1;
    frame.layer = (input[offset] >> 1) & 0x3;
    frame.error_protection = (input[offset++]) & 0x1;
    frame.bitrate = input[offset] >> 4;
    ...

}
```

I assume that the bitfields are not located in a way they intuitively should do. What am I doing wrong?

I am using gcc on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Rhetorical question: So do you suppose your `fff` field above gets mapped to the twelve least significant bits of the int32, or the twelve most significant bits?

Comment: Doesn't thic condition `input[offset] & 0xF0 == 0xF0` should be `input[offset] & 0xFB == 0xFB` ? As I see from this header structure examlpe, next bit after FFF is B https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#/media/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Mp3filestructure.svg

Comment: P.S. I think the problem is not in bit fields, but in bytes order after `reinterpret_cast`. I've tried `uint32_t* val = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(input.data() + offset);` and got `04c8fbff`instead of possibly expected `fffb8c40`

Comment: Thanks, @Gover Nator. Turns out, if I reverse the order of the members in the struct, everything works well.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` used this way has undefined behavior—proper is to `memcpy` into a struct (which is often optimized away) or use C++20’s `std::bit_cast`.

Comment: What is the problem with reinterpret_cast? Why does it have undefined behavior?

Comment: @DavisHerring can you please explain? I've tried to use memcpy, and got the same result.

Comment: @Vahagn: You can’t [**use**](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11) a pointer obtained via `reinterpret_cast` except to convert it back to the original type.  In other words, it lets you hide an `int*` in a `float*` variable (*e.g.*, a struct member you don’t control), but not actually type pun (for most types).  (Also, use @—I saw this only because of the next comment.)

Comment: @GoverNator: You still have to have the struct members in whatever (implementation-dependent) order.  `memcpy` or similar is needed to guarantee that you get any reliable behavior at *all*.